# Repacking Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

Good day!

I have a simple application with http server just like in this guide:

```
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/
```

When I build it and run - it works good.

```
java -jar target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar
```

Now I want to repack this jar file. I do :

```
jar xvf gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar
rm  gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar
jar cf gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar *
```

But when I try to run it with

```
java -jar target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar
```

I get error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in test.jar
```

I tryed to fix it with many ways, but could not find a way how to do it.
Is there any trick?

Thank you.

Comment: Use Maven or Gradle to package your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to reuse the manifest file. If you reuse the manifest file, you'll also get the correct entrypoint (Main-Class/Start-Class). Option `m` and argument `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. If you don't specify the `m` option you'll get a new manifest file that will overwrite your existing one.
- You need to not compress the used libraries. Option `0`. Because of this your final jar may be bigger than what Spring Boot does by default.

`jar cfm0 fne-manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF *`

```
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] files ...
Options:
    -m  include manifest information from specified manifest file
    -0  store only; use no ZIP compression
```

I'm not sure why you want to "repack" it.

Also take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html

Comment: Worked! Thank yoU!